# Can named parameters have aliases?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a method which will assess statistical information relative to distributional parameters:

```
def munch(data:, mean:, standard_deviation:)
  # munch the data
end
```

However, `standard_deviation` is quite a mouthful, and is known by other names (e.g., `sigma`, `sd`) which may be more memorable or convenient for end-users.  I could add more parameters to the method and then manually check that one and only one of the alternative names is used, but that's tedious and ugly.  Is there some way to say that `sd` and `sigma` are aliases for `standard_deviation` so that the following would work?

```
result1 = munch(data: my_data, mean: 20.0, standard_deviation: 3.0)
result2 = munch(data: my_data, mean: 20.0, sd: 3.0)
p result1 == result2  # => true
```

Comment: If you are defining the options, why couldn't you choose the names for the options? There is nothing stopping you from using multiple names for the same value, and it is even common practice. I typically just use a `**options` hash and parse the hash myself.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 I know that's an option, but as stated in the question, I would then have to check that only one of the alternatives was used.

Comment: Why do you have to check that only one of the alternative is used? You can just specify a priority among them. If it is used with more than one, then it is misuse, you don't have to care about it.

Comment: @sawa Because if more than one alternative is used, they may be used inconsistently.  Prioritizing is not a choice I would make, since I want users to feel free to use the one they're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to type too much, and really want to sanity-check, something like this might work?

```
def alias_param(opts, *keys, **args)
  supplied = opts.select { |k, _| keys.include?(k) }
  if supplied.size > 1
    raise ArgumentError, "Multiple aliases supplied: #{supplied.keys.inspect}"
  elsif supplied.size < 1
    raise ArgumentError, "Missing argument: one of #{keys.inspect}"
  end
  opts.values.first
end

def fn(data:, mean:, **opts)
  sd = alias_param(opts, :sd, :sigma, :standard_deviation)
end

fn(data: 1, mean:3)
```

Comment: Assuming the person invoking this method would generally supply one of these arguments shouldn't you check for `1` first rather than use that as the fallout? Maybe something akin to `return opts.values.first if supplied = opts.select { |k, _| keys.include?(k) } and supplied.size == 1`

Comment: Your solution's `args` is unused, but this put me on the right track.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, no, at least not in the automatic way I believe you mean by your comments.

There is no built-in mechanism to define multiple names for one option, and have Ruby automatically return the same value no matter which of those options you reference. By your comment, I assume this is the intended behavior, something akin to an `alias` keyword, and then having the ability to call either by old or new name.

Your only real option is to parse the options manually, which typically shouldn't add *too* much boring boiler-plate code:

```
def blending(**options)
  @mode = options[:mode] || options[:blend_mode] 
  @function = options[:function] || options[:blend_function]
end
```

There is nothing similar to `alias_option :mode, :blend_mode` that will allow you to simply use one of those names and get the value no matter which the method was invoked with. No matter which way you do this, there will be some manual checking to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Amadan's answer, here's what I ended up going with.

```
def check4aliases(opts, *keys)
  supplied = opts.select { |k, _| keys.include?(k) }
  return supplied.values.first if supplied.size == 1
  msg = supplied.empty? ? 
    "Missing parameter: #{keys.first}" : "Use only one of #{keys.join(', ')}"
  raise ArgumentError, msg
end

def munch(data:, **opts)
  parameters = {
    mu: check4aliases(opts, :mean, :mu),  
    sd: check4aliases(opts, :standard_deviation, :sd, :sigma)
  }
  # do actual work with data, mu, and sd
end

test_cases = [
  {mean: 3, sd: 7},
  {mu: 5, sigma: 4},
  {mean: 3, mu: 3, sd: 7, sigma: 7, standard_deviation: 7},
  {mean: 3, sd: 7, sigma: 8},
  {mean: 3},
]

test_cases.each do |parms|
  begin
    p munch(data: 1, **parms)
  rescue ArgumentError => msg
    puts msg
  end
end
```

which produces:

```
{:mu=>3, :sd=>7}
{:mu=>5, :sd=>4}
Use only one of mean, mu
Use only one of standard_deviation, sd, sigma
Missing parameter: standard_deviation
```

I still wish aliasing was an option, but this is usable.